# How can i get variable changes in a service file automatically updates in the parentcomponent?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-components, angular-changedetection

[image]

I have a parent component, where I am calling a service that has a dialog open method.
There I am opening the dialog component. Now, in my dialog component, I have a form and add data button, when I add I am posting the data to the service as an event. After add data button clicked I should not close my dialog is should keep open. My new form data in the dialog service is updated. But how can I send that event to the parent component automatically? it should detect the changes and update the variable in the parent component.

Thanks in advance.
Please provide code/reference/connect to me to solve this problem.

Comment: Instead of an image, you should post your code so we can have your base

Comment: you can read about change detection in detail here https://jagjeets.medium.com/using-angular-change-detection-effectively-f69d6a493c35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a service, then you need a `Subject` into your service, and a getter which will return your subject as observable.
With this solution, every subscribers will be noticed everytime your subject will change.

service

```js
subject = new Subject<any>();

get subject$(): Observable<any> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

parent

```js
constrcutor(private service: YourService) {
  this.service.subject$.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

dialog

```js
constructor(private service: YourService) {}

submit(): void {
  this.service.subject.next(this.form.value); // Replace this.form.value by what you want
}
```